# Samsung Pop 5570 does not connect in Ubuntu 10.10. in development mode

Tags: android, ubuntu-10.10

Adb devices is not listing my Samsung Pop 5570 wen connected in with USB debugging on in ubuntu 10.10

adb devices
?????????? no permissions

i did add the 51-android.rules file in /etc/udev/rules.d folder but still adb devices shows that devices wit ?????? no permissions.

51-android.rules file has the following contents:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"

please let me know if i am missing something

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by appending #samsung in the 51-android.rules file and copying the "adb" command to /bin folder.

$ restart udev

$ cp adb /bin

$ sudo adb kill-server

$ sudo adb start-server

$ sudo adb devices

List of devices attached 
S5570e905be1c   device

Comment: Great! You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow check mark next to the up/down arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I suspect your subsystem name is the culprit (simply try "usb" instead).  However, I am unable to comment as to whether or not that subsystem name is still valid in 10.10 as I do not know what changes have been made to udev.

First step would be to verify that your vendor id is correct with lsusb (that appears to be Samsung's vendor id, but it can't hurt to check).

I am also running 10.10, but I have an HTC device.  Here is my rule file's content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
```

After editing the file, I unplugged my device.  Just in case, I kill adb's daemon:

```
sudo adb kill-server
```

I then reconnected my device and executed "adb devices".  adb started the daemon without sudo.  My device was listed properly.

Comment: I followed your steps and i am still getting the same "no permission" in adb devices. It was happening in windows too even after installing the google usb driver but wen i installed KEIS for samsung , only then my phone got listed

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above problem by prefixing the 51-android-rules file with #samsung, i mean,

'#samsung SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"'.

I killed the adb server and restarted in SU mode and then ran

$sudo adb devices,

i was able to see my device listed.